# Lenguaje C: Posiciones de un alfil en tablero de ajedrez

Tags: c

*Hola!! Estoy aprendiendo a programar y necesito ayuda. Este es el ejercicio:*

**Se tiene una matriz de 8*8, equivalente a un tablero de ajedrez. Leer la posición de un alfil, colocar en la posición que le corresponde una A y en todas las posiciones a las que pueda moverse una P. Llenar el resto de la matriz con asteriscos e imprimir**

***Este es el error**: se imprime siempre una diagonal que no pasa por el alfil, porque según cumple todas las condiciones y filtros que intento ponerle*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main (){
    int a, b, i, j; 
    int tablero[8][8]; 
    
    printf("\nIngrese la posicion del alfil en este formato -> i,j: ") ; 
    scanf("%d,%d", &a, &b); 

// cerar toda la matriz 

    for (i=0; i<8; i++){
        for (j=0; j<8; j++){ 
            tablero[i][j]=0; 
        
        };
    }; 
    
    
// cargar las posiciones por la que puede pasar el alfil        
    
            for (i=a, j=b; (i<8||j>=0); i++, j--){  // valida que el contador no pase los limites del tablero 
                if (a+b == i+j){                        // valida que sea la diagonal que corresponde a a,b. 
                    tablero[i][j]=1;                
            }; }; 
            for (i=a, j=b; (i>=0||j<8); i--, j++){
                if (a+b == i+j){
                    tablero[i][j]=1; 
            }; };   
            for (i=a, j=b; (i<8||j<=0); i++, j++){
                if (i>a&&j>b){
                    tablero[i][j]=1; 
            };  }; 
            for (i=a, j=b; (i>=0||j>=0); i--, j--){
                if (i<a&&j<b){
                    tablero[i][j]=1; 
            };  }; 
                     

    tablero[a][b]=7; // la posicion del alfil 
    
// impresion del tablero de ajedrez 
    
    printf("El alfil esta en %d, %d\n", a, b);  
    for (i=0; i<8; i++){
        for (j=0; j<8; j++){ 
                if(tablero[i][j]==0){
                    printf("*\t"); 
                }; 
                if(tablero[i][j]==1){
                    printf("P\t");
                }; 
                if(tablero[i][j]==7){
                    printf("A\t");
                }; 
        }; 
            printf("\n\n"); 
    };  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente reemplaza los or `||` por and `&&`. El problema que tienes es que los bucles se están repitiendo mientra se cumpla una de las dos condiciones, luego puede (y de hecho sucede) que una de las dos condiciones deja de cumplirse (una coordenada ya no está en el tablero) pero la otra sí ... y eso hace que se escriban diagonales no válidas.

Además, dado que cada bucle lo empiezas en `(a, b)` y te mueves siguiendo una trayectoria legal del álfil, no es necesario los condicionales que tienes dentro de cada bucle

```
for (int i=a, j=b; (i<8&&j>=0); i++, j--) {
    tablero[i][j]=1;                
}

for (int i=a, j=b; (i>=0&&j<8); i--, j++){
    tablero[i][j]=1; 
}

for (int i=a, j=b; (i<8&&j<=0); i++, j++){
    tablero[i][j]=1; 
}

for (int i=a, j=b; (i>=0&&j>=0); i--, j--){
    tablero[i][j]=1; 
}
```

Otros detalles:

- no es necesario poner punto y coma (;) después de una llave
- Acostumbrate a usar nombres de variables que signifiquen algo
- No te acostumbres a declarar todas las variables al inicio del programa. Reduce su vida al mínimo imprescindible
- Tabula bien el código

Comment: Siempre estoy a favor de recomendar usar los streams de C++ sobre las funciones de C, pero en este caso tanto el titulo como el tag de la pregunta indican únicamente C.

Comment: @Pablochaches cierto, vaya despiste!!!